# Multiple elements using vw for width change each each others width

Tags: html, css

I have two elements in my html that are using 'vw' for width.  Element B is hidden until a button is pressed.  When the button is pressed and element B comes on to the screen, element A shrinks.  Why is this happening?  Isn't vw based on the width of the window, therefore it shouldn't change unless the size of the browser changes?

Here is some code and a link to JS fiddle that I made to show this behavior.  If you click the button, the blue sidebar on the left shrinks when the red sidebar on the right appears.
https://jsfiddle.net/MorganLeeR/3xL5pdsm/9/#&togetherjs=rw3KtFwwlq

```
HTML
<body>
  <div class="sidebarLeft">
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <button onclick="showSidebar()">click me</button>
  </div>

  <div class="sidebarRight" style="display:none;">
  </div>
</body>

CSS
body{
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }

.sidebarLeft{
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 25vw;
}

.main{
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebarRight{
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 25vw;
}

JS
let showSidebar = function(){
    let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebarRight");

  if(sidebar.style.display === "none"){
    sidebar.style.display = "flex";
  }else{
    sidebar.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Can anybody explain this to me, because I don't understand this behavior.  Also, a solution to this would be really nice.  Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Added an example that I created and the link to the JS Fiddle for an example of what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your elements are children of the body tag and this body has a display of flex on it.

Try updating your main class to have flex:1; property.

```
.main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

See a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/pgk082td/

Comment: Yep, should have realized that flex was causing that.  Thanks a lot for the help.  I never would have thought to do that as a fix to it.